# "Makeshift flamethrower" or "handmade flamethrower"?

Tags: word-choice

I am trying to describe the causes of a fire that begun when someone used a *makeshift*—or *handmade*—flamethrower.

Some context:

The fire broke out in a prison, when two rival gangs fought each other over a room. An inmate attached a plastic hose to a gas canister, opened the valve and lit a flame, thus turning it into a **handmade/makeshift** flamethrower.

Should I use *handmade* or *makeshift*?

Comment: _Handmade_ often has a positive connotation, indicating traditional craftsmanship. _Makeshift_ indicates that something is created quickly, with the available materials, and does not necessarily live up to the standards of the normal product. I'll leave it up to you which one you want to use :)

Comment: @oerkelens you should turn this comment into an answer!

Comment: Here is an example of a pop culture example of a Makeshift Flamethrower. In Live and Let Die, Roger Moore as James Bond is taking a bath and sees that one of the villains has released a poisonous snake into his hotel room. He takes an aerosol can and a lighter (or was it a cigar), sets fire to the propellant and creates a makeshift flamethrower, dispatching the venomous reptile in the process.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*[Handmade](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/handmade)* is anything made by hand:-

> made by hand, rather than by machine [Random House Dictionary]

But you could have spent weeks assembling a flamethrower with tender loving care and it would still be *handmade*.

*[Makeshift](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/makeshift)* is something pressed into service on the spur of the moment:-

> a temporary expedient or substitute [Random House Dictionary]

So for your purpose, *makeshift* would be better. You could also try *[improvised](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/improvise)*:-

> to make, provide, or arrange from whatever materials are readily
>   available [Random House Dictionary]

Comment: @PabloMarambio - I would say that "makeshift" carries more of the absurd nature of the incident.

Comment: Well... now I can't make up my mind between *improvised* and *makeshift*... :-D

Comment: @PabloMarambio I think a journalist, writing informally, would use "makeshift", but an official of the prison service, writing a formal report, would use "improvised".

Comment: Well, on this [evidence](https://www.mirror.co.uk/news/uk-news/horrific-moment-patients-run-cover-31980776), _makeshift_ has it.